# How to aggregate in Mean.io, a css file only for the current view and not for all application with "modules/aggregated.css"?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mean.io

I created a view with a background of a specific color, I just want the color out in that view and not in the other views of the application. However when I add it to `MeanUser.aggregateAsset ('css', 'signin.css')`, I always get global in the "modules / aggregated.css" therefore all views take that background. Then how to aggregate a css file only for the current view and not for all application? 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that can be done right now.
I guess it needs to live not within teh aggregation as another conditionally loaded resource.
I'll check it with other team members.
cheers
Lior